# NHibernate, injecting service into IUserType using .NET Core ioc container

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to inject a service into a UserType ?

```
internal class MyUserType : IUserType
{
    private static ISerializer _serializer;


    public MyUserType (ISerializer serializer)
    {
        _serializer = serializer
    }
}
```

Tried the why it is suppose to work for all but fails, stating it needs a default parameterless constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is going to be possible as you would need to tap into NH's component creation pipeline/process, which, AFAIK, isn't readily exposed.

You could use property injection with a 'local default'. This would allow you to depend on the `ISerializer` abstraction and replace it when necessary, testing maybe, but rely on a default concrete type in an environment that didn't support IoC.

```
internal class MyUserType : IUserType
{
    private static ISerializer _serializer = new ConcreteSerializer();

    public JsonShippingDetailsUserType()
    {
    }

    public ISerializer Serializer { get; set; }
}
```

N.B. This is a really naive implementation of property injection. If you go with this solution you'll need to 'harden' the code. Mark Seemann's DI book has an excellent example.

Comment: thanks for the answer. As far as I know .NET IoC container doesn't support property injection, so doing that wouldn't help me unless I use others for this job, but i would like to stick with what .NET provides

Comment: I don't think that's going to have any influence. Somewhere in the NH code, I would guess it's doing something like `Activator.CreateInstance(...)` using your custom type. IoC containers aren't part of that process.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that IUserType is managed by NHibernate which uses its own IoC container and by implication does not have access to your IoC of choice and again by implication does not have access to any services registered on your IoC of choice. There is not easy way of injecting, what I can think of is some sort of proxy or to somehow get access to NHibernate internals.